# Hide irrelevant numbers in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have a question concerning the **numbering of sections** in my file. I use the `article` class and `tocloft` to format my table of contents. The relevant commands are:

```
%customize table of contents
\addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand*\contentsname{Inhalt\vspace{0.2cm}\hrule}} %change title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large} %adjust toc title
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1} %smaller spaces between dots
```

I also use this to remove the section numbers:

```
%%hide section number
\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

However, I want the dotted line for my sections as well. But when I do:

```
%%dotted lines for sections
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}{1}}
```

the ToC features some extra number that I do not want to see (in the picture: 1).

[image]

How can I get rid of these numbers?

Comment: Uhhmm... what happens when you remove the `{1}` as part of your redefinition of `\cftsecleader`?

Comment: Danke, Werner, Problem gelöst! Problem solved! I thought I need {1} as value for \cftdotsep, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Cheers and have a nice day!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a wrongly used macro (or typo)